# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Mesh' of undefined

Tags: javascript, pixi.js

I would like to use dragonBones with pixi.js. I got a problem.

When the following line executes in dragonBones, I am getting an error:

`slot.init(slotData, displays, new PIXI.Sprite(), new PIXI.mesh.Mesh(null, null, null, null, PIXI.mesh.Mesh.DRAW_MODES.TRIANGLES));`

The error says: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Mesh' of undefined.`. And yeah, while debugging, I noticed that `PIXI.mesh` is really undefined.

What can I undertake against the error?

I am using [this](https://github.com/DragonBones/DragonBonesJS/blob/master/Pixi/4.x/out/dragonBones.js) file for a dragonbones.

May it be that the problem is in the fact that I am using `pixi.js - v4.5.6`?

Comment: Are you sure you downloaded everything?

Comment: @Bálint, I have `pixi.js - v4.5.6` and `dragonbones.js`. What else should I have?

Comment: I tried it out with codepen and it works, so I have no idea

Comment: What is `codepen`?

Comment: @Bálint, give me a reference to it, please. What version of the `pixi.js` were you using?

Comment: @Bálint, send me your code, please.

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bLweZV

Comment: @Bálint, how can I run it? There is no run button...

Comment: It runs automatically

Comment: @Bálint, so the output in the console is the `Mesh` as far as I get it. And where is PIXI lib over there? How can I have a look at it?

Comment: settings -> javascript

Comment: @Bálint, thank you a lot for the help. So, now I see that there is something wrong with my pixi, but I am working on a pretty big project and it is impossible to just delete the library and paste another one instead. What could be the issue? My library is different in some parts from [the](https://pixijs.download/v4.5.6/pixi.js) real one.

Comment: @Bálint, oh I found the problem. It is just that some modules were turned off. Thank you very much for the attention. Should I delete the question?

Comment: If you found a solution that works, even if it's trivial, it can be worth sharing as an Answer. That way, if another user gets into the same situation and googles for ideas, your experience will help them through. A useful mantra is "post the answer you wish you'd found when you first searched for help"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is that *pixi.js* consists of modules. In big projects it is common to turn off unused modules so that the library itself become lighter.

I just turned on necessary to get rid of errors modules and that is it.

I thought that enabling only `mesh` module would be enough, but actually it was not. After looking through the code I noticed that `mesh` is using a `particle` module in some places, so I enabled the `particle` module as well and it still was not enough.

I ended up enabling all of the modules.